# Saving a review requires a website ID?

Tags: magento-1.7, review

I'm reviewing someone's code that loads, does something to it, and saves it.

```
$review = Mage::getModel('review/review')->load($id);
...
$review->setWebsiteId(0);
...
$review->save();
```

When a review object is loaded, there is no website ID, and the tables don't, either. I'm wondering if this is required or not. The reviews seem to get saves just fine without it. Any ideas?

Comment: From what I know, the website id is not required. but the simplest way to test is to remove the line and try again. See what happens.

Comment: Yeah, it works without it. The only thing that seems to assign the review to a website is the store ID, which is already defined in `$review` when loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a silly answer, but `website_id` is not a field for the review object (`Mage_Review_Model_Review`) and, therefore, not required.